# tabbar and view sizes xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, screenshot, tabbar

I have a simple app with a tabbar. The view size is 480 x 320. The tabbar is 49 x 320. However when i try to take a screenshot using UIgraphicsbeginimagecontext(self.view.frame.size) I get an image of 411 x 320.. 
My background image is 480 x 320 and shows properly in the ios simulator.
However when the screen is captured the background image is cut by the 69 height pixels.
Anyone knows:
1) Where the 20 missing pixels are going (480-49) = 431 while im getting 411
2) Why my background image displays properly in simulator but is cropped when taking a screenshot..
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using `self.view.bounds` for the context size.

Also, are you taking the screenshot before the view has been properly initialized? If you are, this may result in an incorrect size.

Answer (score 0):

The missing 20 pixels are the size of the status bar on the top. Actually your view size height is 460 pixels if you are displaying a status bar on the top. When you take a screen shot using UIgraphicsbeginimagecontext(self.view.frame.size) your size parameter is 320x460, and NOT 320x480 as you expected, resulting in a "cropped" image. (sorry about my english...)